Understanding Verification Steps in Dafny when Using Recursive Functions
I am currently learning Dafny and program verification from the book Program Proofs by K. Rustan M. Leino. I came across this example in the book and I am having a hard time understanding some discrepancies I've found. Here is the code example:
function More(x: int): int
    decreases x
{
    if x <= 0 then 1 else More(x-2) + 3
}


method Example(a: int)
    // requires a == 2 // Always Verifies

    requires a > 1 && a < 3 //Fails when using var b
{
    // assert More(a) > a;  //This snippet always verifies

    var b := More(a);  // This snippet will fail when
    assert b > a;      // using the second require statement 
}

Essentially the function More will always return an integer larger than the input integer and the goal of the method is to verify this fact.
I have a couple of questions about this code:
Why does specifying the precondition “requires a==2” verify for both snippets of code but “requires a>1 && a<3” fails the second piece of code? Aren't both snippets essentially the same?
Also when I choose "requires a == 66" it verifies but if I choose "requires a == 67" then it fails, is there some sort of limitation to the Dafny's ability to prove the assert statements since the function uses recursion?
I am also observing that when I try to generate counter examples the output of the counterexample will be incorrect. Is there a command or option in Dafny that will show me the steps it took to generate a counterexample?
Similarly is there a command or option for Dafny to show its proof steps for simple programs like this one?

I don't have an answer for your first question, but if you add assert a == 2; at the beginning, it verifies no matter what. It's likely that the engine is not trying to infer anything clever from two inequalities.
There is definitely a limit of unrolling from the SMT engine that Dafny does not control, which explains why you would still have limited calculations.
Counterexamples should be renamed, because they are just the state of the verifier when it could not prove that the state was incorrect.
Proofs steps is not automatic yet, but you are welcome to look at the documentation, search for "verification debugging"

That documentation is very helpful thank you for the link.

Dafny requires you to add post conditions to your functions to get useful properties about recursive functions and then you will also need to prove those inductively. I was able to produce the following.
function {:opaque} prod(a: int, b: int): int {
    a * b
}

function MoreVal(x: int): int {
    prod(halfUp(x), 3)+1
}

lemma MoreProdLemma(x: int) 
    ensures isOdd(x) ==> MoreVal(x) == MoreVal(x+1)
    ensures MoreVal(x+2) == MoreVal(x)+3
{
    reveal prod();
}

lemma Something(x: int)
    requires isEven(x) && isPos(x)
    ensures MoreVal(x) == MoreVal(x-1)
{

}
function  More(x: int): int
    decreases x
{
    if x <= 0 then 1 else More(x-2) + 3
}

predicate isEven(x: int) {
    x % 2 == 0
}

predicate isOdd(x: int) {
    x % 2 == 1
}

predicate isPos(x: int) {
    x > 0
}

function halfUp(x: int): int {
    if isEven(x) then x/2 else x/2+1
}

lemma testMore(){
    assert More(-1) == 1;
    assert More(0) == 1;
    assert More(1) == 4;
    assert 1/2+1 == 1;
    assert More(2) == 4;
    assert 2/2 == 1;
    assert More(3) == 7;
    assert 3/2+1==2;
    assert More(4) == 7;
    assert 4/2==2;
    assert More(5) == 10;
    assert 5/2+1 == 3;
    assert More(6) == 10;
    assert 6/2 ==3;
}

lemma halfUpTest() {
    assert halfUp(1) == 1;
    assert halfUp(2) == 1;
    assert halfUp(3) == 2;
    assert halfUp(4) == 2;
    assert halfUp(5) == 3;
    assert halfUp(6) == 3;
}

lemma moreValTest() {
    reveal prod();
    MoreProdLemma(1);
    assert MoreVal(0) == 1;
    assert MoreVal(1) == 4;
    assert MoreVal(2) == 4;
    assert MoreVal(3) == 7;
    assert MoreVal(4) == 7;
}

lemma {:verify } MoreValLemma(x: int)
    ensures x <= 0 ==> More(x) == 1
    ensures isPos(x) ==> More(x) == MoreVal(x)
    {
        if isPos(x) && isEven(x) {
            MoreValLemma(x-2);
            if x-2 == 0 {
                reveal prod();
            }else{
                MoreProdLemma(x-2);
            }
        } else if isPos(x) && isOdd(x) {
            MoreValLemma(x-2);
            if x-2 < 0 {
                reveal prod();
            }else{
                MoreProdLemma(x-2);
            }
        }
    }

method Example(a: int)
    // requires a == 2 // Always Verifies

    requires a > 1 && a < 3 //Fails when using var b
{
    // assert More(a) > a;  //This snippet always verifies
    // assert a == 2;
    var b := More(a);  // This snippet will fail when
    MoreValLemma(a);
    assert b == 4;
    assert b > a;      // using the second require statement 
}

